# script running on windows but not on iOS

Tags: javascript, ios

I have following issue.. This script is working in chrome/mozilla etc. on windows but not in safari iOS. JS is activated.

```
     <script>

      function openWindow(select) {
      var value = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
      window.open(value, 'newwindow')
     }
 </script>
```

What can I do, where is the bug? thanks for helping

Comment: the script is also not running on macos Sierra

Answer (score 0):

Looks like window.open will not work on iPhone/iPad.

You need to create a link and from your code create a click event on that link.

Here's the code:

```
function openTab(url) {
    // Create link in memory
    var a = window.document.createElement("a");
    a.target = '_blank';
    a.href = url;

    // Dispatch fake click
    var e = window.document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
    e.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
    a.dispatchEvent(e);
};

openTab('http://www.google.com'); // will open new tab on iPad and new window on iPhone
```

I got the answer [here](http://whoknew.dk/programmatically-opening-a-new-tab-window-on-mobile-safari-55.htm).

Comment: You would have to change it a little bit but the principle is the same. So for example, if a particular dropdown option is selected, then you call the openTab function.